# How to fade out a bootstrap popover after 5 seconds?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I fade out this popover after 5 seconds? Also, if I click on it, how can I make it hide?

```
   $('ul.menu.fright').popover({
       'placement':'bottom',
       'content':'Look at me!',
       delay: {show:500, hide:100}
    }).popover('show');
```

Comment: judging from this, i guess you want to show the modal when the page loads, hide it after 5 seconds or hide if the user clicks on it. You also want to hide/show it when user clicks on it. check my updated answer. Especially jsFiddle 3 , i think that's exactly what you want.

Answer (score 10):

Well, what @Coding Enthusiast has mentioned, will surely do the job for you. And for the same, I just [made the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fxpnkrba/1/). You can check it out.

What I have done is on the button, but you can replace it

**html**

```
<div class="bs-example">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="Default popover">Popover</button>
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        placement: 'bottom',
        delay: {
            "show": 500,
            "hide": 100
        }
    });

    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').click(function () {

        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.popover').fadeOut('slow');
        }, 5000);

    });

});
```

dont forget the double quote on show and hide ( [issue here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13874) )

Comment: This works very well as long as there is one. If there are multiple popovers on the page, (e.g. I use a glyphicon-question-mark as a popover with some help text attached). After the setTimeout is hit, all the popovers fade out at the same time. To explain, say I have 5 popovers with a timeout of 3000. I click the first popover, then the 2nd, then the 4th over a period of 2500ms. At 3000ms, the last popover clicked will fadeOut at the same time as the first one clicked. I'd expect each popover to have it's own fadeOut clock. Probably not a huge issue but thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 4):

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8635e57h/)

Listen to the hover event on your `ul.menu.fright` . Show your `popover`, then `setTimeout` to hide it after an amount of time.

```
//this is with the hover
$('ul.menu.fright').hover(function(){
        $('ul.menu.fright').popover('show');
        tmp = setTimeout(function(){$('.popover').popover('hide')}, 5000);
});
```

---

I realised my original answer didn't answer your question thoroughly so I tweaked it a little bit. Now it shows automatically on load and it hides after 5 seconds. Shows on click.

### [jsfiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/8635e57h/2/)

```
$('ul.menu.fright').popover({
    placement: 'bottom',
    delay: {
        show: 500,
        hide: 100
    },
    content:'Look at me!'
}).popover('show');
$('ul.menu.fright').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.popover').fadeOut('slow',function() {}); 
    },5000);

});
$('#cokepop').click(function () {
    $('#cokepop').popover('show');

});
```

My JsFiddle two will work wonders but you can improve user experience by hiding the popover if it is shown on click and showing it if it is hidden.

### [JsFiddle 3](http://jsfiddle.net/8635e57h/3/)

All you have to do is change the `onclick` event:

```
$('#cokepop').click(function () {

    if ($("#cokepop").next('div.popover:visible').length){
        $('#cokepop').popover('hide');
    }else{
        $('#cokepop').popover('show');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume that the .popover is a function associated to something you are using to make the popup work but perhaps this code may help you out?

```
$('ul.menu.fright').delay(5000).hide();

$('ul.menu.fright').on('click', function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

set the div to display on load and then the JS will delay the removal for 5000 milliseconds and then hide it. the second function is one for the click and it will hide

Answer (score 0):

This seems to solve the fading of every element that HPWD brought up.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        placement: 'bottom',
        delay : {
            hide : 5000 // doesn't do anything
        }
    }).on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
        setTimeout(function (a) {
            a.popover('hide');
        }, 3000, $(this));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### A solution that works when there are two ore more elements that display popovers

Add a `data` attribute to every element to track the popover visibility on the **html**:

```
data-popoverisvisible="0"
```

**JS**: Trigger manually popover show-hide based on user click: at document ready...

```
$('.element-with-popover').on( 'click', function( evt ) {

    var elem,
        delay;

    delay = 5000; // 5 seconds

    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopImmediatePropagation();

    elem = evt.currentTarget;

    if( $( elem ).data( 'popoverisvisible' ) == 1 )
    {
        $( elem ).popover( 'hide' );
        $( elem ).data( 'popoverisvisible', 0 );
    } 
    else
    {
        $( elem ).popover( 'show' );
        $( elem ).data( 'popoverisvisible', 1 );
        setTimeout( function()  {
            if( $( elem ).data( 'popoverisvisible' ) == 1 )
            {
                $( elem ).popover( 'hide' );
                $( elem ).data( 'popoverisvisible', 0 );
            } 
        }, delay );
    }
} );
```

The popover(s) will show upon user click and hide (if still visible) on a subsequent click.

Visible popover(s) will automatically hide 5 seconds after they have shown up.